# How to deserialize an xml string

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I was trying to deserialize an xml string and I am not getting deserialized the objects.

My xml string looks like

```xml
<Cars>
    <Car>
        <Id>123445</Id>
        <BMW>
          <Id>78945</Id>
        </BMW>
    </Car>
</Cars>
```

```cs
[Serializable()]
[XmlRoot("Cars")]
public class Cars
{
    [XmlArrayItem("Car",typeof(Car))]
    public Car[] Car { get; set; }
}

[Serializable()]
public class Car
{
    [XmlElement("Id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [XmlArrayItem("BMW",typeof(BMW))]
    public BMW[] BMW { get; set; }
}

[Serializable()]
public class BMW
{
    [XmlElement("Id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the code I am trying:

```cs
string str = "xml string like above";
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Cars));
var wrapper = (Cars) ser.Deserialize(new StringReader(str));
```

And I do have couple of sub array objects inside like BMW inside. BUt it is not serializing Car.
Can someone please point out my mistake here?

Comment: Is this problem that your XML has empty elements with no data inside? Or do you get an error message? What do you mean by "it is not serializing Car"? Is the problem with serializing or deserializing?

Comment: What is the error message? Where is the definition of `BMW`?

Comment: @SliverNinja: THere is no error msg but object is not containing any elements.

Comment: @Mark: I updated my question with the data. I dont get error msg just Cars with no array elements with car objects.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `XmlElement` instead of `XmlArrayItem` since the items have no encapsulation tag:

```
[Serializable()]
[XmlRoot("Cars")]
public class Cars
{
    [XmlElement("Car",typeof(Car))]
    public Car[] Car { get; set; }
}

[Serializable()]
public class Car
{
    [XmlElement("Id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("BMW",typeof(BMW))]
    public BMW[] BMW { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try Serializing the expected object into xml and compare.  (The Serialize method is even easier than the Deserialize.)  That'll likely highlight a mis-placed or mis-named attribute.

Comment: One thing is do I need to put every element of the object in the seriazable class or no?

Comment: Each object should be serializable, but I don't believe it's necessary to decorate each class with `[Serializable]`

Answer (score 0):

I have several suggestions and a nice working example for you. First of all, I suggest a different class structure that takes advantage of class hierarchy.

**Here is what you need:**

- CarList - A wrapper class for managing your list of Cars
- Car - A class that provides all of the basic Car properties and methods
- BMW - A specific type of Car class. It inherits the parent Car class and provides additional properties and methods.

When you want to add more Car types, you would create another class and have it also inherit from the Car class.

**On to the code...**

Here is your CarList class. Notice that the List of Car objects has multiple XmlElement declarations on it. This is so that the serialization/de-serialization knows how to handle the different Car types. As you add more types, you will have to add a line here to describe the type.

Also, notice the static Save and Load methods that handle the serialization/de-serialization.

```
[XmlRoot("CarList")]
public class CarList
{
  [XmlAttribute("Name")]
  public string Name  { get; set; }

  [XmlElement("Cars")]
  [XmlElement("BWM", typeof(BMW))]
  [XmlElement("Acura", typeof(Acura))]
  //[XmlArrayItem("Honda", typeof(Honda))]
  public List<Car> Cars  { get; set; }

  public static CarList Load(string xmlFile)
  {
    CarList carList = new CarList();
    XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CarList));
    TextReader r = new StreamReader(xmlFile);
    carList = (CarList)s.Deserialize(r);
    r.Close();
    return carList;
  }

  public static void Save(CarList carList, string fullFilePath)
  {
    XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CarList));
    TextWriter w = new StreamWriter(fullFilePath);

    // use empty namespace to remove namespace declaration
    XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    ns.Add("", "");

    s.Serialize(w, carList, ns);
    w.Close();
  }
}
```

Next, here is your Car class...

```
public class Car
{
  // put properties and methods common to all car types here
  [XmlAttribute("Id")]
  public long Id { get; set; }
}
```

And finally, your specific Car types...

```
public class BMW : Car
{
  // put properties and methods specific to this type here
  [XmlAttribute("NavVendor")]
  public string navigationSystemVendor { get; set; }
}

public class Acura : Car
{
  // put properties and methods specific to this type here
  [XmlAttribute("SunroofTint")]
  public bool sunroofTint { get; set; }
}
```

Load your CarList like this:

```
CarList carList = CarList.Load(@"C:\cars.xml");
```

Make some changes, then Save your CarList like this:

```
CarList.Save(carList, @"C:\cars.xml");
```

And here is what the XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CarList Name="My Car List">
  <BWM Id="1234" NavVendor="Alpine" />
  <Acura Id="2345" SunroofTint="true" />
</CarList>
```

Hope that helps get you started in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found out the problem. I was not including all the properties which I was gettting back in xml. Deserialization won't work if you miss any property.
And I also added this line like this:

```
[XmlArray(Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified),
     XmlArrayItem("BMW", typeof(BMW), Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = false)]
    public BMW[] BMWs { get; set; }
```

If your xml has something like this:

```
<Cars>
  <Car>
    <Id>123445</Id>
    <BMWs>
       <BMW>
          <Id>78945</Id>
       <BMW>
    </BMWs>
  </Car>
</Cars>
```

And then it worked. I didn't have any XSD or schema to generate my opbjects which would be ideal.