# How to serialize attribute

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am trying to deserialize this code

```
 <request>
  <employee id="40407">Test User</employee>
 </request>
```

I've created a class:

```
public class Request
{
    public string employee { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("employee/id")]
    public string employeeId { get; set; }
}
```

Without attribute everything works, but I need the data from attribute "`id`" as well. Once I put `[XmlAttribute("employee/id")]` it doesn't want to work. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154621/add-xml-attribute-to-string-property try this link well give you a much needed example Serialize - 
>Deserialize - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805344/how-to-deserialize-an-xml-string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need following classes to deserialize that xml:

```
[XmlRoot("request")]
public class Request
{
    [XmlElement("employee")]
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("employee")]
public class Employee
{
    [XmlText]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class empl
{
     [XmlText]
     public string name { get; set; }
     [XmlAttribute]
     public int id { get; set; }
 }

 public class request
 {
      public empl employee { get; set; }
 }


 public Test()
 {
    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(request));
    MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
    ser.Serialize(mem , new request { employee = new empl { name="ff", id=6}});
    string dec = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mem.ToArray());
 }
```